# How to hide table columns for mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress

Please help me to sort out the issue.I currently working on a WordPress website project, in that, i use "Table Maker" a plugin which I use to create a table and show the details.In desktop view, it has 7 columns and in mobile version also same 7 columns, now I want to show only first 3 columns only on mobile view instead of showing 7 columns. is there any CSS for that? Please help, I'm a beginner. Thanks in advance URL- https://www.bikersbasket.com/

Comment: add a tag for `css` as well as `wordpress`, and include a link to your code, as no one will want to go to the trouble of setting up their own test environment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has fixed 7 columns so you can use CSS to hide them in mobile. f.e.

```
@media (max-width:768px){
.table_class_name tr td:nth-child(4),.table_class_name tr td:nth-child(5),
.table_class_name tr td:nth-child(6),.table_class_name tr td:nth-child(7){
display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Elvin85, the code didn't fix the issue, I guess, you will find it when you see the webpage direclty-> https://www.bikersbasket.com/test/

In this, I want to show only "image" "brand" and "type" columns in mobile view

Comment: that's because the table has different layout.  Use this one, this would work:  @media (max-width:768px){
.wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(4),.wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(5),
.wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(6),.wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(7){
display: none !important;
}}

Comment: The code worked like a charm, thank you so much Elvin85. You saved my life <3

Comment: Hey Elvin85, there is one more issue, the code which you gave is working only for 1st row and the rest of the rows are showing all the columns.

Comment: @media (max-width:768px){ .wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(8n+4),.wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(8n+5), .wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(8n+6),.wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(8n+7){ display: none !important; }}

Comment: Hey Elvin85, the layout is totally collapsed after adding the last CSS given by you.Please check the webpage and help me out.Thanks in advance

Comment: .wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(7n+1),
    .wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(7n), 
    .wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(7n-1),
    .wpsm-comptable-responsive tr:nth-child(7n-2)
    { display: none !important; }}

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much 